# ucommerce: how to change category template

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-ucommerce

Using uCommerce 2, umbraco 4.7.

I have a category side nav showing the categories using:

```
<a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="CommerceLibrary:GetNiceUrlForCategory($catalogueName, @id)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="@displayName"/>
</a>
```

First of all, when hovering over the links it still shows an old catalogue name, even though I've renamed the catalogue and also hardcoded the catalogue name into:

```
<xsl:variable name="catalogueName" select="'MyCatalogue'"/>
```

When I click on the link generated by GetNiceUrlForCategory I get the standard template that comes with uCommerce started site. I've tried deleting the whole started site, but I just can't get it to link to a template I did for the category.

I still don't quite understand how ucommerce knows which template to use for a category link.

Soren? :)

Cheers,

Matt

Comment: ps. can someone with enough reputation setup a ucommerce tag on SO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer: Change in UrlRewriting.config ... simpelz